# pycharm output is getting shrinked. Need to display all the results. Output window size

Tags: pycharm, output, window-resize

I ran code in python. No matter what the code is, if the output size is big it is giving results in shrinked manner.

Example:

```
Output is:
 [[ 0.11891   0.15255  -0.082073 ... -0.57512  -0.26671   0.92121 ]
 [ 0.42762  -0.11469   0.010506 ... -0.034535 -0.041267  0.2594  ]
 [ 0.418     0.24968  -0.41242  ... -0.18411  -0.11514  -0.78581 ]
 ...
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]]
```

I dont what the ... and shrink results. I need all the results to be displayed. I.e all the numbers. How do I resize output window .

Python Version 3.6
pycharm version 2017.3.2 community edition

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually running and where are you looking for the results? If you are using the Python Console tab and have large dataset then consider using pprint to view a prettified output.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(some_var)
```